# Sort solr from least to highest based on facet count

Tags: solr, facet

This my facet query

> http://localhost:8983/solr/test_words/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=keyword

On searching I get results ordered based on facet count from highest to lowest

Example : {"and" :10, "to": 9, "also" : 8}

But instead I want the results ordered based on facet count from lowest to highest

Example : {"tamil" :1, "english" :2, "french":3}

I also tried

> http://localhost:8983/solr/test_words/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=keyword&facet.sort=count

Which is not giving expected results. Pls help me on this!

Answer (score 0):

The "old" facet interface doesn't support sorting by `asc` as far I know - it's always sorted from most common term to the least common one.

[The JSON facet API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/json-facet-api.html) does however support `asc` and `desc` for sorting:

> **sort** - Specifies how to sort the buckets produced.
>
> `count` specifies document count, `index` sorts by the index (natural) order of the bucket value. One can also sort by any facet function / statistic that occurs in the bucket. The default is `count desc`. This parameter may also be specified in JSON like `sort:{count:desc}`. The sort order may either be `asc` or `desc`.

```
  "facet": {
    keywords: {
      "type": "terms",
      "field": "keyword",
      "sort": "count asc",
      "limit": 5
    }
  }
```